# Call task with arguments in gulp watch

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

In my multi project stack I would like to call inside gulp watch task with arguments like this for single project sass compilation. Is it possible?

```
gulp.task('stack', function() {
    gulp.watch('/stack/sass/**/*.scss', ['css --project Demo']);
});
```

In console this command works

```
gulp css --project Demo
```

but inside gulp.watch

```
['css --project Demo']
```

fails on **"task 'css --project Demo' is not found in your Gulpfile"**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gulp command to take parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53017075/gulp-command-to-take-parameters)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it is not dulicate. In my case I am able to read arguments in 'css' task but it can't be called that way inside gulp.watch - that's my problem.

Comment: Please explain why you can't read the arguments in the css task but they must be specified in gulp.watch which calls the css task.  Hard to determine if the proposed duplicate really is a duplicate without more info.

Comment: @JoãoDeroldo If this question is a duplicate it isn't to the question you propose.  Your exact answer can be found many times on SO.  That question was a duplicate.